# Routes and Url helpers confusion

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm a little confused on the MVC front for this reason, I have the following default route defined;

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
    );
```

When I use a Url helper, i.e.

```
@Url.Action("MyAction")
```

it generates this url;

```
/?action=MyAction&controller=MyController
```

and never finds my action method. How are the Urls generated by the helpers and how do I correct this?

Answer (score 1):

Just use the overload to specify the action and controller:

`@Url.Action("MyAction", "MyController")`

If you use the overload which only takes the action name, the controller is taken from the *current route data*. Default routing doesn't come into it.

i.e.

`@Url.Action("MyAction")`

is equivalent to

`@Url.Action("MyAction", (string)ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"])`

Comment: Specifying the controller still results in the same url, '/?action=&controller='

Comment: P.S Just checked out MSDN library for Url.Action() and it remarks; the URL that is returned by this method has a format like the following; \Home\About

Comment: @JEZ there is something weird going on there, it should generate the address in the documented format, not as a querystring as it is doing in your code. I have never come accross this and have no ideas unfortunately, though I suspect your problem is elsewhere. Are you able to recreate this problem with a very simple example and post the full code?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I must admit I've searched high and low and can't find anything posted that resembles this problem. Urls are being interpreted correctly in the address bar so the route mapping is correct. I'm not sure I can add anything extra to it by example. The UrlHelpers are simply returning a wierd query string url in the cshtml markup??

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I had a web app that was built used WebForms and slowly migrating parts to MVC, to support both I had a route entry which ended up breaking the routing evaluation code and caused the funny action urls

[this blog post](http://bartwullems.blogspot.com/2011/04/combining-aspnet-webforms-and-aspnet.html) fixed my issue